# imshow and plot side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to put side-by-side numpy array displayed as image and seaborn distplot of the same array. I've came up with the following function:

```
def visualize(arr):
    f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios': [1, 3]})

    ax1.imshow(arr)

    flat = arr.flatten()
    x = flat[~np.isnan(flat)]
    sns.distplot(x, ax=ax2)
    plt.show()
```

which produces:
[image]

As you can see, the image has smaller height than the plot. How can I modify my function in order to have the same height for the plot and the imshow?

I want the following placement of the image and the plot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are just so many ways to tackle this. All of the following will give more or less the same image

[image]

#### A. Reduce the available space

You may reduce the available space such that both plots are constrained to the same vertical margins. This can be done by

1. **reducing figure height**

   ```
   fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(6,2.3), ...)
   ```

   [image]
2. **using `subplots_adjust`** to limit the margins

   ```
   fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.7, bottom=0.3)
   ```

   [image]

#### B. Use `InsetPosition`

You may use `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.InsetPosition` to adjust the coordinates of the second axes to match those of the first one.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

def visualize(arr):
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2,
                               gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios': [1, 3]})

    ax1.imshow(arr)

    flat = arr.flatten()
    x = flat[~np.isnan(flat)]
    sns.distplot(x, ax=ax2)

    ip = InsetPosition(ax1, [1.5,0,3,1]) 
    ax2.set_axes_locator(ip)

    plt.show()

arr = np.random.randn(200,120)
visualize(arr)
```

#### C. Use an axes divider

You may create only the axes for the image and then use  `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable` to create a new axes next to it.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

def visualize(arr):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    ax2 = divider.new_horizontal(size="300%", pad=0.5)
    fig.add_axes(ax2)

    ax.imshow(arr)

    flat = arr.flatten()
    x = flat[~np.isnan(flat)]
    sns.distplot(x, ax=ax2)

    plt.show()

arr = np.random.randn(200,120)
visualize(arr)
```

#### D. calculate the desired aspect ratio

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def visualize(arr):
    gkw = {'width_ratios':[1, 3] }
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2,  gridspec_kw = gkw )

    ax1.imshow(arr)

    flat = arr.flatten()
    x = flat[~np.isnan(flat)]
    sns.distplot(x, ax=ax2)

    ya = np.diff(np.array(ax2.get_ylim()))[0]
    xa = np.diff(np.array(ax2.get_xlim()))[0]
    wa = gkw['width_ratios'][0]/float(gkw['width_ratios'][1])
    ia = arr.shape[0]/float(arr.shape[1])
    ax2.set_aspect(float(wa*ia/(ya/xa)))

    plt.show()

arr = np.random.randn(200,120)
visualize(arr)
```

#### E. Dynamically copy positions

You may get the position of the left plot and copy its y-coordinates to the right subplot's position. This is a nice add-on to existing code. The drawback is necessary because subsequent changes to the figure size require to recalculate the positions.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def visualize(arr):
    gkw = {'width_ratios':[1, 3] }
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2,  gridspec_kw = gkw )

    ax1.imshow(arr)

    flat = arr.flatten()
    x = flat[~np.isnan(flat)]
    sns.distplot(x, ax=ax2)

    def on_resize(evt=None):
        ax1.apply_aspect()
        bb1 = ax1.get_position()
        bb2 = ax2.get_position()
        bb2.y0 = bb1.y0; bb2.y1 = bb1.y1
        ax2.set_position(bb2)

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", on_resize)
    on_resize()

    plt.show()

arr = np.random.randn(200,120)
visualize(arr)
```

Comment: in D, why do we normalize by the aspect ratio of `x2` `ya/xa`?

Comment: @peer the data limits of both plots are completely different, hence you need to take those into account.